# Where can I get a definition of how the code is laid out in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I am just starting out learning Visual Basic 2010. I have books and videos. The books all seem to be written for people who have some programming experience, even the books that say they are for beginners.

The videos were great until they started talking about variables. I got the basics of them but they started into complicated variables and I don’t see the need for them right away.  Where can I go to see code for fairly intricate applications written out, with an over lay of definitions of which part of the code is a method as opposed to a class and so on?

Also, I am working at a company that does not use SQL. So I need to use Access 2007 for all of my tables. Is there much of a difference to the coding?

Answer (score 3):

You question is a bit unclear, but I will give the answer a try. VB.Net is an OO language. It allows you to create classes. A class could contain one or more of the following:
Field, Property, Method. Fields and Properties are probably what you refer to as variables. They hold data of some type. Methods are constructs that allow you to perform operations, they may use fields or properties.

SQL Server and Access are Relational Database management systems. They both use SQL. VB.NET uses ADO.NET to connect to either. SQL Server syntax is mostly similar to MS-Access SQL for many simple cases but the syntax can be said to be not the same for all statements specially ones that create database tables and ones that does complex queries.

MS-Access has its own language VBA and has a built in report generator where SQL server does not support VBA and has its own reporting engine.

If you are only writing SQL, you need to get used to the datatypes and the database engine you use quite much to get your work don.

Make sure you learn both VB.NET and MS-Access before you start serious development. Also, you really need to justify this technical architecture since it is not quite the trend these days.

Comment: `Also, you really need to justify this technical architecture since it is not quite the trend these days.` There is nothing in the question to specify if op is working in an IT/software company. Even if that's the case, the simplest justification is some legacy yet still alive project.

Comment: @ Yannis Rizos, you are correct. One can choose any platform he/she wants. I wanted to draw the attention to the importance of selecting a platform.

Answer (score 1):

In VB methods are either written as a function or a sub depending on if they return a value. Classes are essentially a container for related methods and their related variables.
I would recommend you try to get a copy of
[VB.NEt 2010 Step By Step](http://Microsoft%20Visual%20Basic%202010%20Step%20by%20Step)
 as this series is written pretty well for beginners to programming and the Microsoft technologies.